# ReferenceError: toggleTrash is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I have the following function in my controller. When i try to add the $timeout I get reference error as the toggle function comes as not defined. I am new to angular. Does anyone know why this happens?

```
$scope.toggleTrash = function(card) {
    card.clickedtrash = card.clickedtrash ? false : true;
    if (card.clickedtrash == true) {
        $timeout(toggleTrash(card), 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered it with this:

```
$scope.toggleTrash = function(card) {
    card.clickedtrash = true;
    $timeout(function(){card.clickedtrash = false}, 4000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular's $timeout is just a wrapper for window.setTimeout. You can't pass a variable along with the function in the way that you're attempting. You can only do this:

```
$timeout(toggleTrash, 3000);
```

Maybe try creating an anonymous closure, so that the value of `card` is preserved when the callback executes. So:

```
$timeout(function() {
  toggleTrash(card);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the reference error because instead of using `toggleTrash`, you should use `$scope.toggleTrash`.

And use `$timeout` like:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.toggleTrash(card);
}, 3000);
```